# Integrity constraint violation by using Create. Array Item Value is empty

Tags: laravel

I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'sell_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `sellpictures` (`sell_id`, `user_id`, `picture`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, 1, sellimages/9tw7wOLieZc63oiTba99d5oa6kxiaf6RDJsFUo7j.jpeg, 2018-01-05 15:51:22, 2018-01-05 15:51:22))"
```

As you might see the 'sell_id' is empty, but I can't explain it, because I see with dd() that the array is not empty:

```
array:3 [
"sell_id" => 1
"user_id" => 1
"picture" => "sellimages/9tw7wOLieZc63oiTba99d5oa6kxiaf6RDJsFUo7j.jpeg"
]
```

The following code is just out of a helper class.

```
class UploadImages 
{
public function storeSellPicture($picture)
{
...
            $sell = new Sell();

            $sellid = $sell->getOpenSellID(); //gets me e.g. 32

            $sell->addSelllImages([
                'sell_id' => $sellid,
                'user_id' => auth()->id(),
                'picture' => $filename
            ]);
 ...
 }
```

I could of course save the data in the Model Sellpictures, but I use the Relationships to insert a new record.

```
<?php

namespace InstaFood;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Auth;
use \Carbon\Carbon;

class Sell extends Model
{

protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

public function sellImages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Sellpicture::class);
}
public function addSelllImages($image)
{
    //dd($images) shows the correct data
    return $this->sellImages()->create($image); //Gives the error
}
...
```

The model of Sellpicture is guarded

```
<?php

namespace InstaFood;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Sellpicture extends Model
{
//
protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at']; 
}
```

Why is the value of sell_id gone while creating a record?

Comment: what is sell_id for, add it to $protected = ['sell_id',....] ;

Comment: protected $fillable = [ 'sell_id'];

Comment: what does `$sell->getOpenSellID();` do exactly ?

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi sell_id is the ID of the Model Sell that contains every information of a sell. Sellpicture is a Model that contains many pictures of one sell. With create I'm mass assigning so I'm not protecting it.

Comment: @Sohel0415 I chose $guarded so I won't use $fillable

Comment: @YouneL pretty easy, it gets me the id of the table Sell with where user_id = auth()->id and complete = 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have not included in `$fillable` fields;

```
<?php

namespace InstaFood;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Auth;
use \Carbon\Carbon;

class Sell extends Model
{

protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'sell_id'];

public function sellImages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Sellpicture::class);
}
public function addSelllImages($image)
{
    //dd($images) shows the correct data
    return $this->sellImages()->create($image); //Gives the error
}
```

Comment: But why? It's written:  "Of course, you should use either $fillable or $guarded - not both"

Answer (score 0):

You should save the new `Sell` instance before getting its relationship method, and you don't need to pass `sellid` either:

```
$sell = new Sell();

$sellid = $sell->getOpenSellID(); //gets me e.g. 32

// save first
$sell->save();

$sell->addSelllImages([
    'user_id' => auth()->id(),
    'picture' => $filename
]);
```

Comment: I think I have a logical error and can't see it. I cannot use it, because there is an open record that is not completed. So I don't want to save a new one, instead I need the current ID

Comment: in this case you should save images without using `sellImages` relationship method because you cannot call it by an non existing model

Answer (score 0):

NO Solution until now. I changed the code and don't use the relationship. It works like that.

```
            $sell = new Sell();

            $sellpicture = new Sellpicture();

            $sellid = $sell->getOpenSellID();

            $sellpicture->create([
                'sell_id' => $sellid,
                'user_id' => auth()->id(),
                'picture' => $filename
            ]);
```